# How to return row count of SSAS query in SSMS as in DAX Studio

Tags: powerbi, ssms, ssas, daxstudio

When I run a SSAS query in DAX studio, it returns the query result with total row count of the resulting query. Is it possible to achieve the same in SSMS?

E.g. the following SSAS query

```
EVALUATE
{
    ( 2006, "December" ),
    ( 2007, "January" )
}
```

in `SSMS`

[image: SSMS]

in `DAX Studio`
[image: DAX Studio]

Currently, the SSAS query result is returned in `SSMS` without row count. I am not sure if I need to make some changes in `SSMS` settings in order to activate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presently, the only way to have the row count of the executed query returned is by wrapping the query inside `COUNTROWS`

i.e.

```
RETURN {COUNTROWS(lastVar)}
```